# onClick image that toggles music

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I want to make an image that when I click on it, music can be toggled on and off. I am ready to use jquery, javascript, and or bootsrap.
This is my example.

```
    <head>
    <style>
    #music{
    display:hidden;
    }
    </style>
    <img src="image url" id="image" onClick="function"/>
    <audio src="music" id="music"></audio>
```

I already have music available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding the audio won't stop it. What you need to do is use [`audio.pause()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Controlling_media_playback) and [`audio.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Controlling_media_playback)

You can make a toggle function like this:

```
var toggleSound = function() {
  if (audio.paused == false) {
      audio.pause();
  } else {
      audio.play();
  }
};
```

and to call it, replace `$("#music").toggle();` with `toggleSound();`

Here's a live example http://jsfiddle.net/jTh3v/181/ (I used a button instead of image, but it's the same)

Comment: Thank us so much, it worked perfectly!!!!!!!!!!!!!! My website is better than ever now!

Answer (score 1):

**Your HTML:**

```
<img src="image url" id="image"/>
<audio src="music" id="music" style="display: none"></audio>
```

**Your jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#image").click(function() {
$("#music").toggle();
});
});
```

Remove your styling for the `display:hidden` and you're good to go. ;)

Edit: I removed your `onclick=""`, there's no need for it when you're using jQuery. Plus the .click handler has proven to be more efficient in my experience.